# Using variable DB Connections in different identical Kettle Jobs/Transformatioins

Tags: database, variables, connection, etl, kettle

I've read thru many related topics here, but don't seem to find a solution. Here's my scenario:

- I have multiple identical customer databases
- I use ETL to fill special tables within these databases in order to use as a source for PowerBI reports
- Instead of copying (and thus maintaining) the ETLs for each customer, I want to pass the DB connection to the Jobs/Transformations dynamically

My plan is to create a text file of DB connections for each Customer:

cust1, HOST_NAME, DATABASE_NAME, USER_NAME, PASSWORD
cust2, HOST_NAME, DATABASE_NAME, USER_NAME, PASSWORD
and so on...

The Host will stay the same always.

The jobs will be started monthly using Pentaho kitchen in a linux box.

So when I run a Job for a specific customer, I want to tell the job to use the DB connection for that specific customer, i.e. Cust2. from the Connection file.

Any help is much appreciated.
Cheers & Thanks,
Heiko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run a similar scenario daily in my work. What we do is we use Batch files with named parameters for each client, this way we have the same package KJB/KTR's that run for a different client based on these parameters entirely.

What you want to do is set variables on a master job, that are used throughout the entire execution.

As for your question directly, in the connection creation tab you can use those variables in Host and DBname. Personally, we have the same user/pw set on every client DB so we don't have to change those or pass user/pw as variables for each connection, we only send the host name and database with the [Named Parameters](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Named+Parameters). We also have a fixed scheduled run that executes the routine for every database, for this we use a "Execute for each input row" type JOB.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters!

When you define a connection, you see a small `S` sign in a blue diamond on the right of the `Database Name` input box. It means that, instead of spelling the name of the database, you can put in a parameter.

The first time you do it, it's a bit challenging. So follow the procedure step by step, even if you are tempted to go straight to launch a ./kitchen.sh that reads a file containing a row per customer.

**1) Parametrize your transformation.**
Right-click anywhere, select `Properties` then `Parameters`, fill the table:

- Row1 : Col1 (Parameter) = HOST_NAME, Col2 (Default value) = the host name for Cust1
- Row2 : Col1 = DATABASE_NAME, Col2 = the database name for Cust1
- Row3 : Col1 = PORT_NUMBER, Col2 = the database name for Cust1
- Row4 : Col1 = USER_NAME, Col2 = the database name for Cust1
- Row5 : Col1 = PASSWORD, Col2 = the database name for Cust1

Then go to the `Database connection` definition (On the left panel, View tab) and in the Setting panel:

- Host name: ${HOST_NAME}         -- The variable name with a "${" before and a a "$" after
- Database name: ${DATABASE_NAME}  -- Do not type the name, press Crtl+SPACE
- Port Number: ${PORT_NUMBER}
- Database name: ${USER_NAME}
- Database name: ${PASSWORD}

Test the connection. If valid try a test run.

**2. Check the parameters.**
When you press the `run` button, Spoon prompts for some `Run option` (If you checked the "Don't show me anymore" in the past, use the drop-down just near by the `Run menu`).

Change the values of the parameters for those of Cust2. And check it runs for the other customer.

Change it on the `Value` column and the `Default value` column. You'll understand the difference in a short while, for the moment check it works with both.

**3. Check it in command line.**
Use pan from the [command line](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0L0/0Y0/070).
The syntax should look like :

`./pan.sh -file=your_transfo.ktr -param=HOST_NAME:cust3_host -param=DATABASE_NAME:cust3_db....`

At this point, you have a small bit of trials and errors, because the syntax between `=` and `:` varies sightly with the OS and the PDI version. But you should get by with 4-6 trials.

**4. Make a job**
Do to the parallel computing paradigm of PDI, you cannot use the `Set variable` step in a single transformation. You need to make a job with two transformation : the first reads the csv file and define the variables with the `Set variable` step. The second is the transformation you just developed and tested.

Don't expect to make it run on the first trial. Some versions of the PDI are buggy and requires, for example to clean the default value of the parameters in the transformation. You are helped with the `Write to log` step which will write a field in the log of the calling job. Of course you will need to first put the parameters/variables in a field with the `Get variable` step.

**In particular, do not start with the full customer list!** Set the system up with 2-3 customers before.

Write the full list of customer in your csv, and run.

Make a SELECT COUNT(customer) on your final load. This is important, because you will probably want to load as many customer as possible, so to continue the process even in case of failure. This is the default behavior (on my best memory), so you won't probably notice a failure in the log if there is a large number of customer.

**5. Install the job**

In principle, it is just a `./kitchen.sh`.

However, if you want to automate the load, you will have a hard time for checking that nothing went wrong. So open the transformation an use the `System date (fixed)` of the `Get System Info` step and write the result with the customer data. Alternatively you can get this date in the main job and pass it along the other variables.

If you have concerns about creating a new column in the database, store the list of customers loaded by day, in another table, in a file or send it to you by mail. From my experience, it's the only practical way to be able to answer to a user that claims that their biggest customer was not loaded tree weeks ago.

Comment: Hi, just implemented your steps 1-3 which works fine. Thanks so far for that :-) 

As for step 4, the set variable step returns an error: "Only 1 input row was expected to set the variables and at least 2 were received"

My csv looks like this:

Customer;Parameter;Default Value
cust1;DATABASE_NAME;dbcust1
cust1;HOST_NAME;host1
cust1;PASSWORD;password
cust1;PORT_NUMBER;5432
cust1;USER_NAME;postgres
cust2;DATABASE_NAME;dbcust2
cust2;HOST_NAME;host1
cust2;PASSWORD;password
cust2;PORT_NUMBER;5432
cust2;USER_NAME;postgres

Comment: m  Set variabes step like this:

Field name Variable name Variable scope type Default value
Customer CUSTOMER Valid in the root job 
Parameter PARAMETER Valid in the root job 
Default Value DEFAULT VALUE Valid in the root job

Comment: Sorry for the mess - I'm not too familiar with formating comments :-(

Comment: But anyways I can live without the csv. I'll just run multiple kitchen jobs. Thanx for ur solution!

Comment: Multiple jobs is a perfect solution. Do not forget that something will get wrong at some point in time. At that time you will be happy of knowing which job made a mistake. Maybe you put the name of the job and the date on each record getting in.

Comment: Thx, I did that already. For each job I have added an "error job" which will send an Email with the details of the error log attached.

Comment: Thank you @AlainD for your detailed steps. The most important point is to not type the variables but to choose from options using Ctrl+Space for windows and for Mac, for which I was having trouble finding right keys, its Cmd+Shift+Space